# Hive external table delimiter corrupting after creation

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, cloudera, bigdata

I have a source files with broken pipe delimiter. My hive external table also i have created with broken pipe delimiter. But after creating the table , i'm seeing the delimiter like 'j'. I cannot able to query from the table also.

**Created Syntax :**

Tried with ASCII value

```
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  eventdate date)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u00A6'   
STORED AS PARQUET
```

and with pipe as well

```
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  eventdate date)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '¦'   
STORED AS PARQUET
```

**After table creation :**

```
PARTITIONED BY (                                                           
   eventdate date)                                                             
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED                                                       
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'j'                                                 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
```

Please help to suggest on the above part. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you are using

```
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  eventdate date)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'   
STORED AS PARQUET
```

instead of

```
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  eventdate date)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'   
STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

probably it is because you are telling hive that your data is stored as parquet. let me know if that fix the problem